# How do I print a range from a incremented value to a decremented in python

Tags: python, function, printing, range

I am new in python and I want to print a range, but when I run the program dosent print anything.

```
dec_value=int(input("ENTER THE DECREMENTED VALUE"))
for i in range(100,0,dec_value):
  print(i)
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try enter a negative number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dec_value` (the step of the range) needs to be negative if the start number is larger than the end number, or it will return an empty range. If it returns an empty range, the loop won't run since there's nothing to iterate over.

If start < end, the step should be positive, else, it should be negative.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following to normalize  negative or positive inputs:

```
dec_value = int(input("ENTER THE DECREMENTED VALUE: "))
for i in range(10, 0, -abs(dec_value)):
    print(i)


>>> ENTER THE DECREMENTED VALUE: -5
10
5

>>> ENTER THE DECREMENTED VALUE: 5
10
5
```